# PermissionError: [Errno 13] when using tkinter for an image

Tags: python, image, tkinter

Hello I am trying to make a python script that takes an image file from a computer and turn it into text. At the moment, I have the following code

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pytesseract


Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = filename

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(filename))
```

However this gives me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(filename))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 409, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 412, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 287, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 258, in run_tesseract
    raise e
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/william/theimage.jpg'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the `tessearct_cmd` is supposed to be set to an image file? I think it's supposed to point to the actual `tesseract` command. This error is telling you it can't execute the image, which makes sense since images aren't executables.

Comment: Thanks so much, I used this code
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
and it now works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this: `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = filename` is absolutely **wrong**.

tesseract_cmd should have your tesseract engine executable path.

you need to find where you installed tesseract.

```py
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = <path_to_tesseract_engine>
# example 
# pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "/some_folder1/some_folder2/...
# /<where_you_installed_tesseract_cmd>/tesseract.<whatever_is_the_extension_for_executables_on_mac>"
```

you get `permission error` because you set the `tesseract_cmd` to link the path to `your image` and when you actually use `pytesseract.image_to_string(<your_image>)` ofcourse it raises permission denied because the image is used by the `tesseract_cmd` process.

after you set your engine.

`this is gonna be fine`

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(filename))
```